# Search Bar To Find Users

Tags: php, mysql, search

Opening new topic because got progressed and now need a bit more help.

I have created find.php:

```
         <h5>Search: </h5>
        <form action="search.php" method='get'>
            <input type='text' name='fullname' size='25' /> 
            <input type='submit' value='Search' /> 
    </form>
```

And another page search.php

```
         <h5>Search: </h5>
        <form action="search.php" method='get'>
            <input type='text' name='fullname' value='<?php echo $_GET['fullname']; ?>' size='25' /> 
            <input type='submit' value='Search' /> 
    </form>
   <?php
   $fullname = $_GET['fullname'];
   $terms = explode(" ", $fullname);

   $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE ";

   foreach($terms as $each){
        $i++;

        if($i == 1)
            $query .= "fullname LIKE '%$each%'";
        else
            $query .= "OR fullname LIKE '%$each%'";

   }  

    $query = mysql_query($query);
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

        if($numrows > 0){

            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                $id = $row['id'];
                $fullname = $row['id'];
                $profile_picture = $row['profile_picture'];

                echo "<img src='www.secrethashtags.com/uploads/profile_picture/$profile_picture' height='50' width='50'> <br><a href='www.secrethashtags.com/profile.php?id=$id'>Aviv Day </a></br>";
            }

        } else
            echo "No #Results.";


   ?>
```

Now, i'm trying it on my website and it tells me no results.
i'm trying to find all users with fullname like fullname in mysql table.

and if it finds, echo the user profile picture 30x30 and his name linked to his profile page.

but it doesn't work. Hope for some help.

Comment: Any errors being reported? Have you outputted the query and seen what is being built? You should define `$i` first and increment it at the end of each iteration. This is going to open you to SQL injections as well. You should switch to `mysqli` or `pdo` and use prepared statements.

Comment: @chris85 nothing, it just like numrows = 0 and goes to the else function and print no results.

Comment: Before `$query = mysql_query($query);` output the query. Try running on db.

Comment: @chris85 oh, now i see it says: SELECT * FROM users WHERE fullname LIKE '%Aviv%'No #Results.
and i understand it search for Aviv in full name when actually full name is Aviv Day. i dont see how to make it search for Aviv Day and no aviv

Comment: try checking for errors on your query and, as always, use mysql*i* instead of mysql. `if (!$result = mysqli_query($db,$query)) {echo mysqli_error($db)}`

Comment: @chris85 Yes, can't get it done!

Comment: That query, `SELECT * FROM users WHERE fullname LIKE '%Aviv%'`, doesn't return any results when run on the db?

Comment: You need to be very careful when using user input to build SQL. If I'm not mistaken, I could write a search input that would delete your database with the code you have. If I did an input of something along the lines of `';tabDELETEtabFROMtabUserstabWHEREtabFullNametabLIKEtab'` where the *tab* is a tab character I'd delete everything from your Users table.

Comment: @chris85 no it doesn't

Comment: Okay look at the record(s) in your db that you are trying to select/find what does it have for the full name?

Comment: @chris85 records does have Aviv Day and another user name Manole Bogdan

Comment: There must be something different about about it. Can you output the table structure and/or a screenshot?....or if you comment out the foreach loop and take the `where` off the query what results do you get?

Comment: [link](http://snag.gy/a4IhD.jpg)

Comment: @chris85 if i do what you said i'm getting: SELECT * FROM users No #Results.

Comment: Arrg, plain text passwords. Delete that link and reset that user's password. Are you connected to the correct DB?

Comment: @chris85 yes i'm connected to the right one. i need to change it to get all word including space, instead of only first word

Comment: Oh, I took a step in the wrong direction. If `SELECT * FROM users WHERE fullname LIKE '%Aviv%'` at the DB level isn't returning results there must be something strange about the record itself. I haven't encountered this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change this line and it will fix your issue.

```
$query .= " OR fullname LIKE '%$each%'";
```

Comment: care to share the reason why this should fix it? future visitors to the question will also like to know.

Comment: The concatenation was creating the invalid SQL statement. It needed a space to make it valid. I just added the space in there.

Answer (score 0):

> at first you have to change from `mysql` to `mysqli`

change this part of code

```
//define $i     
foreach($terms as $each){
            $i++; // increment at the end of each iteration  

        if($i == 1)
            $query .= "fullname LIKE '%$each%'";
        else
            $query .= "OR fullname LIKE '%$each%'";

   }
```

and you have to display the sql error to know what realy hapen

```
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());;
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

and here

```
$id = $row['id'];
$fullname = $row['fullname'];
```

Comment: So now i get SELECT * FROM users WHERE fullname = Aviv DayYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Day' at line 1